# Alternative to double dabble for binary to BCD conversions in FPGA?

Tags: fpga

I want to design a binary to BCD converter. While the double dabble algorithm is easy, it also takes a long time to execute because you can't do the whole calculation in parallel.

Are there any alternatives to double dabble that also don't require multiplication/division?

I'm looking for a generic algorithm that can work on any size.

Comment: Brutal solution : A large ROM. For example, if you use FPGAs, one 18kB Xilinx BlockRAM can convert a 10 bits binary number.

Comment: I'm looking for a generic solution that can work on any bit size. I'm unsure if an algorithm that meets my conditions actually exists at all.

Comment: There are fast decimal adders for decimal FPUs, you can try to split the binary numbers into chunks, convert each part to decimal, then use decimal adders.

Comment: Well, splitting the binary numbers into chunks is exactly what the bin to BCD conversion is supposed to do.

Comment: You don't require multiplication or division. You could unroll the loop and use instantiated or concurrent procedure calls for an add3. Envision generate statements or a loop statement with sequential procedure calls knowing the number of bits. See the block diagram at [Convert 8bit binary number to BCD in VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871792/convert-8bit-binary-number-to-bcd-in-vhdl/23899472#23899472). Wider inputs means more sequential operations (ganged add3s). Binary to BCD conversion doesn't parallelize well.

Comment: Why is execution time important? I assume you're using BCD only to display a final result to the user, not for internal computation or data storage right? Binary is always more efficient than BCD, except for displaying on a user interface. And users don't need updates any faster than about 100ms, if that.

Comment: No, I actually want to use it for computation. I know binary is more efficient. I want to design some circuits and publish the code online, but for that I have to know how fast it actually is.

Comment: You can use a higher radix. So do 2, 3 or 4 bits per shift. For example [PoC.arith.convert_bin2bcd](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/arith/arith_convert_bin2bcd.vhdl) can be configured in input bits, output digits and a radix. It's a trade-off between resources, Fmax and latency.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. Could you explain how that works? I can't really deduce the algorithm from the VHDL code.